The reason why scheme theory emerged.
In any history, there is a cause-and-effect relationship. So I became curious about the situation in which the scheme theory came to appear. In other words, I'm curious about what problem was left unsolved and led to the emergence of scheme as a solution. Or I wonder if scheme emerged as a more minor concept in the progress of researching a certain concept. Furthermore, how the sheaf theory and the scheme theory are connected in the development process.

Have you read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheme_(mathematics) ?

Yes, but I think what's written on the wiki is too brief

The biggest immediate problem that scheme theory was needed for was the reduction of algebraic varieties from characteristic zero to characteristic p. Given an algebraic variety over $\mathbb{Q}$ defined by a bunch of polynomials, you can scale the polynomials to have coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$ and then reduce them mod $p$ to get an algebraic variety over $\mathbb{F}_p$. Weil's algebraic geometry couldn't handle this, so people like Neron and Shimura constructed their own (private) languages. Scheme theory allows you to define schemes over $\mathbb{Z}$ which greatly clarified things.
